# Delete Group Member Exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException' with message '(#3) Unknown method'

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm learning how to create a web app to manage my group using Facebook PHP SDK v5.0. When I delete my group members, system throw an exception:

> Exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException' with message
>   '(#3) Unknown method'.

This is my code

```html
public function removeMemberByMemberId($group_id, $memberid, $fb, $access_token){
        try {
            $request = $fb->delete('/'.$group_id .'/members', ['members' => "'" . $memberid . "'"], $access_token);
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
}
```

Please help me!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You can only remove members for groups created with your app (App Groups).

Comment: ...and app/game groups are deprecated according to the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Thank you for information of you two! I'll close this question!